# tcpd[3674]: connect from unknown (unknown) - Am I being hacked?

Tags: networking, server, security

Earlier today I had 7 tcpd processes on my server running at 100% cpu for a long period of time.  Looking into syslog I found a lot of lines like this:

```
 tcpd[11447]: connect from unknown (unknown)
```

A larger snippet is at the end of this question. Digging through syslog I eventually found several IP addresses that I didn't recognize.  I added them to the hosts.deny file and manually killed the tcpd processes.

I just discovered another connection from a new ip address, which I also killed.

Is this some kind of denial of service attack and if so, what can I do about it?

Note: this server is running 12.04 LTS updated with the latest security updates. Since my original posting of this question I have installed some firewall rules using ufw. I allow only ssh connections and the connections necessary for my offsite backups. So far I have not seen any of the above mentioned tcp connections.

Here is a larger snippet of my syslog:

```
    Feb 18 03:45:12 odie tcpd[11447]: connect from unknown (unknown)
    Feb 18 03:45:12  tcpd[11447]: last message repeated 199 times
    Feb 18 03:45:12 odie rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock begins to drop messages from pid 11447 due to rate-limiting
    Feb 18 03:45:18 odie rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock lost 6671 messages from pid 11447 due to rate-limiting
    Feb 18 03:45:18 odie tcpd[11447]: connect from unknown (unknown)
    Feb 18 03:45:18  tcpd[11447]: last message repeated 199 times
    Feb 18 03:45:18 odie rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock begins to drop messages from pid 11447 due to rate-limiting
    Feb 18 03:45:20 odie console-kit-daemon[1928]: WARNING: Failed to add monitor on '/dev/pts/4': No space left on de
    vice
    Feb 18 03:45:24 odie rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock lost 6785 messages from pid 11447 due to rate-limiting
    Feb 18 03:45:24 odie tcpd[11447]: connect from unknown (unknown)
    Feb 18 03:45:24  tcpd[11447]: last message repeated 199 times
    Feb 18 03:45:24 odie rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock begins to drop messages from pid 11447 due to rate-limiting
    Feb 18 03:45:30 odie rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock lost 6810 messages from pid 11447 due to rate-limiting
    Feb 18 03:45:30 odie tcpd[11447]: connect from unknown (unknown)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? Are you behind a FireWall? Please [edit] your question and add this information...